# Echo 2 SQL ROW Value in PHP

Tags: php

Sorry I'm just beginner in PHP MYSQLi. 
I want to ask if how to call 2 sql row  value here is my code

```
<h2><?php echo $userRow['agentFname']; ?></h2>
```

I want to add 'agentLname' beside 'agentFname'

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1...

```
<h2><?php echo $userRow['agentFname'].' '.$userRow['agentLname'] ?></h2>
```

Option 2...

```
<h2><?php echo $userRow['agentFname'] ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $userRow['agentLname'] ?></h2>
```

Comment: I will choose the option 1. Maraming Salamat, Kuya!

Answer (score 1):

Then just print it:

```
<h2>
<?php
    echo $userRow['agentFname'];
    echo " ";
    echo $userRow['agentLname'];
?>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<h2><?php echo $userRow['agentFname'].' '.$userRow['agentLname']; ?></h2>
```